# Custom Polygons / User Editable Shapes

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Currently, on a web application I am working on, one of our clients asked for a feature I am not quite sure how to implement.  We have a Google Map on the main page and our client wants to be able to draw on that map for presentations.  I have seen two examples of what our client wants.  The first example is at http://www.scribblemaps.com/ where I can draw lines, shapes, and in the Pro version "block arrows" which is what our client is asking for.  However, this application only allows you to create the map on their site and then save it as a JPEG.  Our client wants to do this within our application.  Scribble Maps accomplishes this by using Adobe Flash and I'm guessing they place a Google Map in the background which I am not sure would be the best route for us.

I also found this blog http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2011/11/make-your-map-interactive-with-shape.html describing User Editable Shapes.  On this example I am able to create shapes and Adjust the size post creation.  I was wondering if it were possible to create a custom polygon like a block arrow as another button on the map where the user could add that shape to the map and edit the size?  I realize the user could use the custom polygon button but I know our client won't want to draw their own arrow each time.

*** EDIT ***

So that I am clear I am not asking anyone to write any code for me but point in the direction of information.  I want to know if it is possible to pre-create polygon shapes like "block arrows" so that our client can click and drag to draw this arrow on the map like circles or rectangles using just the Google Maps API.

Comment: What exactly are you asking for? A ready made  piece of code to draw polygons shaped as arrows? Of course it can be done, but you are the one who is getting paid to do it. Otherwise you can tell your client to contact me. :-)

Comment: If you take the time to read my post you will see that I am not asking for anyone to write any code.  I am very capable of writing code without your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I had vary similar tasks to perform in my project.
You can let them draw shapes on the map. In my project I have let he user draw there shape by clicking on map and adding a marker on each click and when he clicks on the existing marker all the makers form a closed polygon. Then you can save it to database. As far as that editing part you mentioned above, you can set editable property of polygon to true to let them play with polygon.

Hope this helps you in your project.
Happy Coding !! Good Luck

Comment: Thanks for the response but as I mentioned I do know you can draw any shape by using the custom polygon tool and clicking points to draw lines and closing the polygon similar to the Pen Tool in Illustrator.  What I am trying to find out is if there is a way I can create a pre-fabricated shape like a "block arrow" or "octagon" or something that you can just click and drag to draw like the circles and rectangles.

Comment: You mean [custom overlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/overlays#Custom_Overlays)

Comment: Thanks for the link but I read that before and it isn't sufficient for what I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a late answer but I think this one would be useful for you.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/user-editable-shapes